# Using double brackets gives -bash: conditional binary operator expected

Tags: bash

Why does this doesn't work

```
if [[ screen -ls | grep -q "Hello" ]];
 then 
    echo "Hello"; 
fi
```

It gives the errors

```
-bash: unexpected token `|', conditional binary operator expected
-bash: syntax error near `-ls'
```

But this works

```
if screen -ls | grep -q "Hello";
 then 
    echo "Hello"; 
fi
```

Shouldn't it be the other way around? How can I fix the double brackets.

Comment: Why do you need the double brackets if it works without the double brackets?

Comment: I want to learn

Comment: Bash expects a conditional expression inside double brackets. Executing a bare command is not part of a conditional expression syntax (but you can execute a command inside a command substitution `$(...)`).

Comment: @Leon Can you provide a link for further reading on this explantion?

Comment: Explore this resource (check the BashFAQ section too): http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide